# Run pytest inside a script (if name...)

Tags: pytest

I have the next file with tests

```
import pytest
from httpx import AsyncClient
import sys
import config
from main import app


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_register():
    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test") as ac:
        response = await ac.post("/register", )
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

I want to run it like

```
if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    pytest.run()  # Or something alike
```

How I can do it? I need it to assign name '**main**' to this module, because the main module (which import above) has a constraint like: `if __name__ == '__main__'`, so without it tests will not be run indeed.

Comment: [`pytest.main()`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest-main)?

Answer (score 0):

`pytest.main()` would run `pytest` in the current working directory and this would include your file depending on the filename (e.g. if the filename starts with `test_`). To run `pytest` on the current file only you can run:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main([__file__])
```

Comment: You should not use the basename, because it will unnecessarily stop working executing the file from some other path.  Just use `__file__` directly (I've edited as such).